# Is there a standard Haskell function that does numerical clipping?

Tags: haskell, math

I have the following code:

```
clip n = if n < 0 then 0 else n
```

It's in the same "category" as `abs`, `ceiling`, `floor`. I don't suppose there is a standard function that does this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure there is one:

```
clip = max 0
```

Comment: The right shift and `xor` approach is probably worth mentioning—it's better in some contexts.

Comment: If you right-arithmetic-shift all the way (the usual right shift for `Int` is arithmetic), then you'll get all 0s if the number is positive or 0 and all 1s if the number is negative. `xor` was the wrong operator, though. I meant flip the bits and `.&.` it.

Comment: @dfeuer OK, although that sounds very special-cased, something for LLVM or GCC to take care of, not to write in Haskell.

Comment: The LLVM backend will often try to be clever about such things; the native code generator will not. Bringing GCC into it will cost you a 5ns FFI call and throw a monkey wrench into the optimizer.

Comment: @dfeuer Yeah I meant GCC in general, not from Haskell.

Comment: @dfeuer why not make it an answer so that the OP can decide what fits his problem?

Answer (score 4):

A side note, for clipping n within a closed interval [a,b], namely

- n if a <= n <= b
- a if n < a
- b if n > b,

consider

```
clip :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> a -> a
clip n a b = min b $ max n a
```

or if you like point-free-style:

```
clip :: Ord a => a -> a -> a -> a
clip a b = (a `max`) . (`min` b)
```

Comment: `max` and `min` are both commutative operations, so that can just be `clip a b = max a . min b`.

Comment: Thanks a heap for the comments / improvements.